# HTML Newsletter blurs images

Tags: html, css, image, newsletter

I noticed that whenever I resize my screen, it somehow recalculates the size of my image and makes it blurry. This happens instant in chrome, but after resizing in safari. I have been trying to wrap my head around this for a while now but I can't seem to fix it.

What is causing the blurring?
I've quickly inserted only one of the images but this happens with all.
Code is based on Zurb's Ink.

https://jsfiddle.net/bnL1tyku/

```
img {
    outline: none;
    text-decoration: none;
    -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;
    width: auto;
    max-width: 100%;
    clear: both;
    display: block; }
```

Comment: Not happening for me in chrome. Maybe a cause of slow internet?

Comment: Happening for me in chrome as well and I'm testing with all local files so it's not slow internet ;) Besides in safari when you initially load the page they are all sharp, until you start scaling.

Comment: Doesn't happen here in Chrome, but I'm more worried about the difference in behaviour between Chrome and Mozilla.

Comment: I don't follow. It's meant as an example design of how a newsletter can scale. I just need the images fixed...

Comment: Load a much higher resolution image to prevent loosing the image loss on resizing. If you're worrying about the image size use a compression software. :)